# puppeteer.js inside loop performance question, reusing browser instances?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm making a scraping app, I have an array of urls from a single domain with headless puppeteer.js.

For each url I have I launch a browser, check if I'm logged, if not, log and write cookies for next iteration of the loop (this is soI don't have to login each time).

After that I do some classic scraping, close the page and close the browser, back to the next iteration of the loop and the same again.

I was wondering if it would be possible to increase the performance and overall quality of my operations, I think opening and closing chrome instance in loop is pretty CPU intensive, I don't want memory leaks either, can I alter my code to reuse browser or page intances for my script.

```
async scrapeForResults()
    {
        let urls = [ ... ]:

        for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)
        {
            let response = await this.scrapWebForData(urls[i]);
            console.log('Contact info scraped - - - - - - - -');
            
        }
    }
```

puppeteer.js action, I do this for each url of my array, all urls are from the same domain:

```
async scrapWebForData(url)
    {
        
        let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true});

        const context = browser.defaultBrowserContext();
        context.overridePermissions("https://www.facebook.com", []);
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(100000);
        await page.setViewport({ width: 1365, height: 623 });
        
        if (!Object.keys(cookies).length)
        {
            this.handleLoginCookies(page);
            let currentCookies = await page.cookies();
            fs.writeFileSync('./cookies.json', JSON.stringify(currentCookies));
        }
        else
        {
            await page.setCookie(...cookies);
            await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
            //DO ACTION HERE
            
        }
        
        await page.close();
        await browser.close(); 
    }
```

Comment: Probably, setup the `browser` outside of the loop and pass it in

Comment: also [fb tos](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php)